# Using generics to avoid looping and casting

Tags: java, generics

I have an Object Conversion Class that converts from my domain level objects to DTOs.

I effectively have the following structure

```
class RuleGroupDTO {
List<RuleDTO> ruleDTOs;
// other members
```

`EvaluationRuleDTO` and `AssignmentRuleDTO` both extend from RuleDTO

My API for conversion is as follows:

```
public RuleGroupDTO convert(RuleGroup ruleGroup);
```

So when I pass in my domain `RuleGroup` to the convert class, it looks at a code associated with the `RuleGroup` and then constructs either `EvaluationRuleDTO` or `AssignmentRuleDTOs` encapsulated within the `RuleGroupDTO`.

When I retrieve back my RuleGroupDTO, I know that it will contain a `List<RuleDTO>` that is either `List<EvaluationRuleDTO>` or `List<AssignmentRuleDTO>`.

However, to get the correct class version I need to loop through the `List<RuleDTO>` and cast to either `List<EvaluationRuleDTO>` or `List<AssignmentRuleDTO>`

This seems messy, and I am thinking that I can leverage some generic concepts to avoid performing this loop + cast.

What would be a possible approach to changing my API or object structure to take advantage of generics here?

Comment: `public <T extends RulesGroupDTO> T convert(RuleGroup ruleGroup);`?

Comment: Generics helps in avoid casting, but I don't think you can avoid looping.

Comment: Is it the case that the RuleDTO's converted from a single RuleGroup will either be all Assignment or all Evaluation rules?

Comment: Alex - yes they will. thinkstepp - if I can avoid casting why would I need to loop?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a set amount of types and you want them separate, then return a pojo with the various types separated into different collections, e.g.:

```
public class DTOResult {
  public List<EvaluationRuleDTO> evalDTOs;
  public List<AssignmentRuleDTO> assignDTOs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `List<RuleDTO>` to avoid casting, and for god's sake don't write a loop.  Make RuleDTO implement a visitor pattern that allows any consumer to handle either kind of subclass in a type-safe manner.

Java [sucks](http://jazzjuice.blogspot.com/2010/10/6-things-i-hate-about-java-or-scala-is.html) at variant types.